# Open an external url from a web page without the warning

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to open an external url "https://stackoverflow.com/" on a new tab on opening a page in internet explorer. I have the code for it but when I try to open the page it gives me this dialog box screenshot below. Once I click on Allow Blocked Content then it opens my page in a new tab :

[image]

I do not want the user to make any changes to his Internet explorer settings. Is there any changes I can make my code open the "https://stackoverflow.com/" url without the above dialog box ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function LoadF() {
        window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body onload = "LoadF()">
<center><a target="_blank" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a></center> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE thinks you're trying to open a popup. Is treating it like a regular anchor tag not an option?

Answer (score 1):

As a shameless copy-paster, It is my duty to notify you that this question was already answered. 
To summarize, there are **two major points** to note:

1. This bar will only appear when running the page locally, and should not therefore appear when loading the page from a web server.
2. You can add a line **at the top of your code** to tell IE that the local file is safe: `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`